# Why is the variational approach in BCS theory at 0 Kelvin?

Tags: superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate

Where in the variational approach of BCS theory is it assumed to be at $T=0\: K$ (temperature). You get the energy gap equation from minimising the ground state energy but this equation is different when doing it with the bogoliubov transformation (because this is at finite temperatures). Isn't the ground state the same for finite temperatures and should it not be minimalised the same way as in the variational approach?

Answer (score 1):

Because at $T=0$ *all* the particles are in the ground state and hence participate in $|\Psi_{\text{BCS}}\rangle$, so you just need one type of creation operator $c^\dagger$ for the Cooper pair:
$$ |\Psi_{\text{BCS}}\rangle = \prod_\mathbf{k}(u_\mathbf{k}^\ast+v_\mathbf{k}^\ast c^\dagger_{\mathbf{k},\uparrow} c^\dagger_{-\mathbf{k},\downarrow}),$$ and the BCS energy gap you get from the minimisation is the binding energy of a Cooper pair at $T=0$.

At finite temperatures, however, you can have (thermally) excited that do not participate in $|\Psi_{\text{BCS}}\rangle$:
$$  b^\dagger_{\mathbf{k},\uparrow} |\Psi_{\text{BCS}}\rangle = 0.$$

These are basically related to the Fermi-Dirac distribution deviation from a step function at $T\neq 0$.

The gap equation then, understandably, becomes temperature dependent, and the gap itself is $0$ at the critical temperature $T_{\mathrm{c}}$. I.e. Cooper pairs only have a favourable binding energy for $T<T_{\mathrm{c}}$.